# Javascript code is deleting row on hit enter and button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Javascript code is deleting row on hit enter and button click
Below code is working deleting row on button click but even if i am entering text in input field and if i press ENTER it is deleting the row also. I am using this for multiple fields generated dynamically.

How can i avoid the deletion of row on pressing enter?

**Javascript**

```
//===== delete the form field row
$("body").on("click", ".remove_node_btn_frm_field", function () {
   $(this).closest(".form_field_outer_row").remove();
});
```

Comment: A button element default type is `submit`, and this will also capture enter key, try setting the button element to `type="button"`

Comment: @Keith thanks i was missing this tag on this button but on all other it was there. Please post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HTML button element's default type is `submit`, a side effect of this is that is also captures the enter key.

If this button is not meant to submit a form, you will want to make sure the type is set to `button`.

```
<button type="button">
```